ViewPager2 with reordering logic for next fragment always being to the left or to the right
Is there any possibility to make viewPager2 with disabled userInput
viewPager.setUserInputEnabled(false);

and control pages reordering in the way of substitution fragments always to the left or to the right, skipping the animation part of showing others fragments between this moving ?
For example, we have viewPager2 with loaded fragments like this:
screenFragments.add(new LoginScreenFragment(...));
screenFragments.add(new EmailConfirmationScreenFragment(...));
screenFragments.add(new ConnectChildScreenFragment(...));
screenFragments.add(new HomeScreenFragment(...));

We are at HomeScreenFragment and we want to go to EmailConfirmationScreenFragment, but with animation of HomeScreenFragment going from right to left and EmailConfirmationScreenFragment also going from right to left.
We can do something like this if we reorder list of those 4 fragments in FragmentStateAdapter like this, removing fragment from list and adding it to the end of sequence (for example):
public class ScreensAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    @NonNull
    private final ArrayList<ScreenFragmentBase> _screenFragments;

    ...
    
    public void reorderItemIndex(ScreenFragmentBase item, int to) {
        _screenFragments.remove(item);
        _screenFragments.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


But this logic will cause the stupid animation of reordering those fragments, which can't be disabled.
Is there any way of creating and preloading all fragments on app start, which will be used like tabs, but with logic of being able to animate this way?
Maybe, I shouldn't use viewPager2 for this logic and just use default FragmentManager transactions? But then there won't be the possibility of preloading those fragments on start?
